# Download Visual Studio 2010 express No Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have just downloaded visual studio's 2010 but there is no template to a master page or anything to then use with it.

I will be using C# programming eventually, with asp.net

This is what i get when i select create new project.

i want to use .net framework 3.5. please help, what else needs to be downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Have you read express version limitations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C# 2010 Express only support following default projects templates:

> Windows Forms Application
>
> WPF Application
>
> Console Application
>
> Class Library
>
> WPF Browser Application
>
> Empty Project

To use ASP.NET Web Applications you need this: 
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web

Answer (score 4):

For web development, you should download [Visual Studio Express for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web).

The C# express version does not include web templates.

Answer (score 3):

You need Visual Studio Express for Web not for Dekstop

And you should use the new 2012 version.

[Here is the link](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-web)